# Java using an image inside a .jar file

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I know questions like this have been asked before, but I have looked and tried a lot of the answers and none of them work. I am trying to use an image inside a .jar file. The image is stored in the directory /world/maps/map1.jpg.

```
            BufferedImage bigImg;
            try
            {
                bigImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/world/maps/" + name + ".jpg"));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e + ": is the error");
                bigImg = null;
            }
```

Thanks for the help.

forgot to make it clear but class file is in the same directory as image

Comment: do you add this directory to your classpath?

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: this is the error -- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! Yes i did add it to the class path, I first compiled as zip and could see the file inside

Answer (score 1):

If you directory tree is something like:

```
SomeClass.class
world
|--maps
   |--image.jpg
```

You can use some reference like:

```
SomeClass.class.getResource("./world/maps/image.jpg")
```

If the class is inside some another directory, just add `../` to the path.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work, On compile is says incompatible types (requires bufferedimage got url), also they are in same directory, i made it /world/maps because that was an answer on a similar thread. It didn't work when it was a .jar file

Comment: I don't understand. `BufferedImage bigImg = ImageIO.read(SomeClass.class.getResource("./world/maps/image.jpg"))` works correctly.

Comment: Are you using Jdk 5 or higher to compile? Some tools like Maven can use an older version of the Jdk by default.

Answer (score 0):

The class on which `getClass()` is called must reside in the same jar. And the path must be case sensitive.  Are you sure that `name` is `"image"`?

Comment: yes it works when done from the command line (java start), the point is I need it to work from a .jar file